# bazel generate_workspace - which one to use

Tags: bazel

I found several instances of bazel's `generate_workspace` from `bazelbuild` organization - each with different commits.

https://github.com/bazelbuild/migration-tooling
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/master/src/tools/generate_workspace

I just wonder - which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Generate external dependencies from Maven projects](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/generate-workspace.html), use [migration-tooling](https://github.com/bazelbuild/migration-tooling).

REF: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44847159]